# What should i do so the div's height set to most height to all div's

Tags: jquery, css

I have some div and they have different size, so i want to equal the height of all the dis's.

> The problem is the below code works fine if i refresh the page **after
>   the page load**.

What should i do so the div's height set to most height to all div's??

```
$(function() {
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("div.product").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
    $("div.product").css("height", maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: You probably want to run that code on window load rather than dom ready, otherwise it may apply the height before all page assets have finished loading (which sounds like the issue you are describing)

Comment: sounds fine, I just forgot about the `window.load`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new style rule and append it to head section:

```
$(function(){
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $("div.product").map(function(){
                                            return $(this).height();
                                    }).get());
$("<style type='text/css'> .product{ height:"+ maxHeight +";} </style>").appendTo("head");
});
```

Comment: If i add this event to head directly?? I think it also works fine. Right??

Comment: Yes it will as its inside ready function and maxheight is computed when dom is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use JavaScript to achieve this while it can be achieved with CSS only?

Wrap the product divs in a new element wich has display set to flex so all the child elements will be stretched out to this parent.

```
.parent { 
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer

```
var maxheight;

$('div.product').each(function(){
    var currHeight = $(this).height();
    if(maxHeight < currHeight) {
        maxHeight = currHeight;
    }
});

$('div.product').height(maxHeight);
```

Edit: Code indentation.

Comment: I don't DV(downvote) you, as i said my code works fine. Why you make / change my event? Its not the problem.